# How can I control showing of views on iPhone

Tags: iphone

Here is the scenario. I have 4 view controllers v1, v2, v3, v4 which are displayed using 4 tabbarcontroller of iPhone. now I push another view sv1 to v1 (while I am viewing v1, I use pushviewcontroller). Now if I press v2 tabbar (while I am viewing sv1), and then press v1 I see sv1. However, I do not want this behavior. I want to show v1 instead of sv1. How can I remove sv1 from its parent's view when v2 is clicked?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe a small code would help to understand, particularly how do you pushviewcontroller sv1, where do you push it?

Comment: [appDelegate.nv pushViewController:sv1 animated:YES]; while I am viewing v1 where nv is UINavigationController

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[navigationController popToRootViewController animated:NO]` in your `viewWillDisappear` method.

Comment: I have used that, it goes back to the previous screen but the navigation bar is not drawn at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing subviews and navigation controllers.  When you push a view to a navigation controller, you push it to the end of a stack of views.  The view at the end of the stack is displayed.  You can pop that view from the stack, and the next view in the stack gets displayed:

```
[self.navigationController popViewController:YES];
```

With subviews, you have to remove then from their parent:

```
[sv1 removeFromSuperView];
```

In your case, you want the first solution.